# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation when adding to a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to move selected images from nested subdirectories. I am match sku from an excel file to the image name (which is also the sku number). Any that matches are then moved into a new folder.

My challenge when I try to create a dictionary to save my full directory I am being faced with the following error message.

File "c:\printing\python\data_clean.py", line 56
fullpath_filelist = {file: os.path.join(root,dirs, file}
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
#! python 3
# Create clean version of data file

import openpyxl, webbrowser, sys,re, os, shutil

print('Opening workbook')

#*********************
Main_Searchterm = 'Find'
Sub_Searchterm  = 'Marine'
Data_path = 'C:\Printing\Python\data\datafile.xlsx'
Image_folder = 'C:\Printing\Python\data\images'
Sorted_folder ='C:\Printing\Python\data\sorted'
#**********************

def find_category():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Data_path)

    sheet = wb['Sheet1']


    #This looks for the main search term and put it into column 6
    for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
        category = sheet['E' + str(rowNum)].value  #This control which column to search from
        keywordRegex= re.compile(Main_Searchterm)
        mo = keywordRegex.search(category)
        try:
            if mo.group() == Main_Searchterm:
                sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 6).value = Main_Searchterm #This control which column to add the new search term
        except:
            pass

    #This looks for the sub search term and put it into column 7
    for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
        category = sheet['E' + str(rowNum)].value  #This control which column to search from
        keywordRegex= re.compile(Sub_Searchterm)
        mo = keywordRegex.search(category)
        try:
            if mo.group() == Sub_Searchterm:
                sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 7).value = Sub_Searchterm #This control which column to add the new search term
        except:
            pass


    wb.save(Data_path)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Data_path)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

filelist = [] #List of all files in directory and subdirectory
fullpath_filelist ={}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Image_folder):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(file)
        fullpath_filelist = {file: os.path.join(root,dirs, file}

for filename in filelist:
    for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    #for rowNum in range(2, 3):
        image = sheet['H' + str(rowNum)].value  #This control which column to search from
        final_path = os.path.join(root,Main_Searchterm,Sub_Searchterm,filename)

        if str(image) == str(filename):
            shutil.move(filename,final_path)

find_category()
```

Comment: This is usually caused by copy and pasting from another source into your IDE.  The indents at the start of each line either all need to be tab characters, or all spaces.  Your IDE may have a setting to show whitespace markup so you can find the problem lines, or maybe an auto format option to automatically fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the IDE, ctrl-F for the '\t' and replace with '    ' (4 spaces)